# How to configure the windows git bash env?

Tags: windows, git

I want to use a batch to start gitbash.

bash.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

but I can't use path env.
for example:

```
  $ ruby -v
  sh.exe": ruby: command not found
```

How to configurate the env manually? for example: add ruby,java,maven env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As on linux, you should add it to your `PATH`. For example, add the following line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Ruby193/bin
```

and restart GitBash to take it into account